# Why Object class have init function in Flex 4.5?

Tags: apache-flex, function, init

Create new Object in Flex 4.5 like this:

[image]

As you can see int line 5, the function marked as overridden, why do we need this?

Comment: I do not understand your question.  What component have you created?  What did you extend?  How did you create the new method?  By hand or some other way?  Nothing is marked as overriden in the short snippet of code you've shared with us.  What do you think is marked as overriden?  How is it marked as overriden?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com question been edited

Comment: I was able to replicate that, but only when creating the class in the default package.  I'm not sure why.

Comment: Object class doesn't have a init function in Flex 4.5. The IDE just falsely reports that it does. If you call super.init() from your init function, you'll get a runtime error. Now the real question is why  the IDE thinks that the Object class has a init function.

Comment: I think you found a bug for FB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a bug of your IDE.

Just try FB 4.7 bete with Flex SDK 4.6, no issue. 
[image]